# HttpSession is sometimes "null" in case of JAX-WS webservices

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jboss5.x

I am working on JAX-WS webservice and sometimes on heavy load i am getting HttpSession "null". This is how I am getting the session:

MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
HttpSession session=((HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession();
if(session==null) {
    logger.warn("Session is null");
}

I am using JBoss 5

Thanks | Abhi

Answer (score 0):

change the code to to:

session=((HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession(**true**);

Comment: what does this mean? I mean what will happen if we pass "true" as an argument?

Comment: it will create new session, if session is null and not created yet.

Comment: Still the same result. I guess bydefault the create parameter to getSession is true.